# Line break not happening in CSV file being generated by IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, csv

I am using following PHP code to generate CSV file:

```
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-control: private");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Type: text/csv");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=site_list.csv");
```

The CSV file is generated successfully in all browsers. But the file generated by IE, when opened with MS Excel, shows all the data in single line.

PS:

- Files generated by other browsers (FF, Google Chrome) are behaving perfectly.
- I am using "\n" for line breaks.
- Using "\r\n" does not help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `\r\n` as your newline? I know some versions of IE have some weird issues when it comes to carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

Add \r\n and it should be included by double quotes

```
'Line 1' . "\r\n" . 'Line 2'
```